# Get Element Containing Hyphen - Eve

Tags: python, jsonschema, eve

I receive 404's when performing a get request for elements containing hyphens. I am running the python-eve API framework.

```
$ curl -i http://api/words/apple
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

$ curl -i http://api/words/a-be
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue? A cursory search returned nothing. My suspicion is that it relates to the lookup in my schema:

```
    'additional_lookup': {
    'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
    'field': 'word'
},
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the regex does not include hyphens. Try setting `url` to something like `\w+(?:-\w+)+`.

Comment: Wow it is such an honor to get an answer from you...thanks for the awesome software. I am still learning.